# javascript syntax error, missing ";"

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a form with potential errors in the form defined in php.  I'm used javascript to change the form action depending on whether errors are present or not.  I've converted the php error variable, $errors using json_encode so I can use it in javascript.  Running the file in Firefox I get the following error in Firebug:

> Syntax error: missing ;

before statement `var errors = "{"firstnameErr:......etc}`, with the pointer at the letter f in firstnameErr. It looks like I have the errors in the json_encode object.

Here is the javascript:

```
 <script type = "text/javascript">
    function switchFormAction() { 
    var errors = [];                               
    var errors = "<?php echo json_encode($errors); ?>";
    if(!empty(errors)) {
    alert("Please correct these errors");
    }                                        
    else    {
    var element = document.getElementById("regForm");
    element.setAttribute("action", "serraInsertForm.php");
    return true;
    }
    }
    window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("regForm").onsubmit = function()
    switchFormAction();
    }
</script>
```

Probably something simple but I can't work it out.  Javascript and json are new to me.
Appreciate any help stackoverflow can offer.

Comment: It's very likely that json_encode is outputting double quotes when you are echo'ing `$errors`.

Comment: try as `var errors = '<?php echo json_encode($errors); ?>';`

Comment: Also, javascript doesn't have an `empty` function, unless you have written and defined it somewhere yourself.

Comment: `var errors = "{"first...` is definitely not valid syntax. Get your double quotes right.

Comment: `document.getElementById("regForm").onsubmit = function()` this line will give you problems aswell

Comment: @celeriko why would it? Oh.. there's no function body in OP's code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Losing the quotes around here ought to do it.

```
var errors = "<?php echo json_encode($errors); ?>";
```

Should probably be:

`var errors = <?php echo json_encode($errors); ?>;`

Comment: Get suggestions from each respondent.  MarcB and a-h were right on.  Correcting one error usually uncovers others.  I'm working on that (trying to learn more javascript) and if I can't solve it I'll ask for more help. luchiangelo

Answer (score 5):

```
var errors = "<?php echo json_encode($errors); ?>";
             ^---                                ^--
```

The indicated quotes are not necessary and are in fact causing the problem. json_encode() will produce whatever quotes/brackets are necessary to turn the data in `$errors` into syntactically valid Javascript. You're producing:

```
var errors = "{"somekey":"somevalue"}";
             ^--start string
               ^--end string
                ^^^^^^^ undefined variable
```

All you need is

```
var errors = <?php echo json_encode($errors); ?>;
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick!  That part of the code now works fine!